# How to remove QML binding on property from C++?

Tags: qt, qml, qproperty

With QML a property value can be based on another object property's value, it is called [binding](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html) and it will update your value everytime the property you depend on is updated.

Like in this example, the `implicitWidth` of `CppItem` is half of the parent's width and the `Text` will fill the layout. If you resize the window, the `CppItem` width is updated.

```
Window
{
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        CppItem {  implicitWidth: parent.width * 0.5  }
        Text    {  Layout.fillWidth: true  }
    }
}
```

In my problem CppItem is a `QQuickItem` with some C++ code, and in some specific cases the C++ code will set the `implicitWidth` with the following code.
*I know I could use `setImplicitWidth` but I am not sure it would make a difference for my problem, and anyway you can not do that if the property is not declared in C++ but in a loaded QML file.*

```
setProperty("implicitWidth", 100);
```

The property value is set but the QML binding is not removed. So the C++ code above is not equivalent to the QML code :

```
cppItem.implicitWidth = 100
```

With the C++ code, any change on `parent.width` will trigger an update on `cppItem.implicitWidth` and set again the value `cppItem.implicitWidth`.

How can I remove this binding from C++ ?

Comment: `How can I remove this binding from C++ ?` if you did your app design right, you shouldn't have to. Touching any QML from C++ is considered bad practice, and things like property bindings are not even in the public C++ API, so that's even worse.

Comment: @dtech I agree that a better design would avoid this situation, but you don't always choose the design. And anyway the behaviour is not intuitive, so I think it is nice to point this out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`QObject::setProperty`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#setProperty) in C++ does not break the binding previously made in QML.

But using [`QQmlProperty::write`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlproperty.html#write-1) does break the binding.

```
// setProperty("implicitWidth", 100); --> Does not break binding
QQmlProperty::write(this, "implicitWidth", 100);
```